# How to use JQuery to toggle (hide/show) all lines in a text area that contain certain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area that I need to show/hide certain lines based on some simple criteria (whether a string is present or not).  I want the user to be able to check a checkbox to show or hide these lines.

Basically, I will attach a click handler to the checkbox, and if clicked -- I need to get the value of the text area, then apply the filtering.  If they uncheck the box, I want the original results to show again.

```
    $('#filter_button').click(function() {

        var unfilteredArray    = $('#unfilteredtextarea').val().trim().split('\n');

        for (var i = 0; i < unfilteredArray.length; i++) {

    if (VALUE IS PRESENT){
     HIDE LINE;
    } else {
     DISPLAY LINE;
    }
        }

    });
```

I know I can read in EACH line using a FOR loop in Javascript and check each one, but if the textarea contains 4000+ lines, that can be expensive.

Is there a way I can use JQuery to simplify this or a different way I should be thinking about this?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No matter what the syntax looks like, if the filter is being applied directly to a textarea (as opposed to modifying how the client-server interaction works) the underlying process will be that each line needs to be inspected for that value. A `for` loop will at least be much less expensive than the `.each()` iterator. Question: can you split at `'/n'` once the string is already sent out to the DOM? I know you can on a data set, but I don't know if the character persists inside a node.

Comment: Is this a read-only textarea? If not, what should happen when the user modifies the text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the textarea's scrollTop property to restrict the rows that you're iterating a cross?

This at least allows you to bound the expense of the search op